# Mathematical or logical issues

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am working with Parse.com and have created a profile page where users enters a variety of information like age, name, and sets their minimum age allowed and maximum age allowed through seekbars. These information get recorded, and when populating the list of users, with support I have created a matching system that returns the list of users who within the age range of the current user.

Below is my code to achieve this:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();


           query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge);
           query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge);
```

This seem to have partially worked. In the same that when the minimum age and maximum age values of two users are equal, than it would show that user since its fall within that age range, however, if the minmum age of the current user was 22, and the other user on the list was 20 than it would not show. This code only seems to work when both values of maximum and minimum are equal. My question is this i set it up properly, because it seems that unless the values are identical even if users in that list falls within that age range, they would not be displayed.

If you require further information let me know.
Clarification:
For instance,
Assuming there are 2 users in the list and current user is signin as user A
If users A minimum age is 25 and maximum age is 50 
If users B minimum age is 25 and maximum age is 50
User B would be displayed as a potential match

Where I have issues is the following
If users A minimum age is 22 and maximum age is 50
If users B minimum age is 22 and maximum age is 48
User B would not be displayed when it should since it falls within that range

If users A minmum age is 20 and maximum age is 50
If users B minmum age is 22 and maximum age is 50
User B would not be displayed regardless if user B age is 25 or 30.

Comment: Can you provide some example data along with example values of `minimumAge`, `maximumAge`, and the actual and expected output?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask - this is extremely unclear

Comment: If I understood correctly, A's age must be in the range specified by B and vice versa B's age must be in the range specified by A. You are just checking one of the conditions.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want all users which have an age between the given minimum and maximum ages. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correcrt or if the minmum age is equal to the other users minimum age, or maximum. Hence, returns all users who have at least the minimum age and at most the maximum age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the minimum age of all users to the minimum age of the current user and the maximum age of all users to the maximum age of the current user. Instead, you want to compare the **age** of all users to each of these:

```
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It make sense, and I believe it should solve the issue, but when I ran the application it jump into the else statement else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
      "Error loading user list",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to return Users if they match one OR the other of those.  If that is the case, you can use the .or method.  The following is an example of it's usage from the Parse Docs:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> lotsOfWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player");
lotsOfWins.whereGreaterThan(150);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> fewWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player");
fewWins.whereLessThan(5);

List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(lotsOfWins);
queries.add(fewWins);


ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    // results has the list of players that win a lot or haven't won much.
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the OP needs an "and" operation with the comparisons reversed from this example. (i.e. the users with ages between the two values). Of course, it shouldn't be difficult to adapt this answer to the OP's needs.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses, and for your assistance user216. Indeed you are correct @Code-Apprentice the "and" operation would have to be considered. Its esstiantly show the matches of the individuals who have at least the same minimum age, or at most the maximum age

Comment: @user3907211 You should be able to adapt this answer to your needs. I suggest browsing the `ParseQuery` documentation for an `and()` method.

Comment: I figure I could adjust the code to my need, but I am still puzzled in figuring out what was the actual issue with my code, and as to why it is not resolving it

Comment: @user3907211 the issue was that just putting the two constraints on the 1 query like you did, implies an 'and' query.  The query will only give you results that match the first constraint, AND the second constraint.

Comment: This where I am partially confused. Shouldn't both of the constraints be used? Like first one if he is at least minmum age, and second if he is at most maximum age to determine the list of users who falls between that age group.